# No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined:: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-boot

I have 2 data source beans, I am using spring boot , spring data, I have marked one of the datasource bean with @primary annotation, I am still getting error : `No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined:: expected single matching bean but found 2.`

below are my 2 database configuration classes:

DatabaseConfiguration.java

```
package com.staples.mpe.config;    
@Configuration        
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="com.staples.mpe.repository",entityManagerFactoryRef ="mpeEntityManager",transactionManagerRef = "mpeTransactionManager")        
@DependsOn("mpeTransactionManager")      
public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, "spring.datasource.primary.");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null && propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName") == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    "cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                    Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"));
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null || "".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("url"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", propertyResolver.getProperty("serverName"));
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("url", propertyResolver.getProperty("url"));
        }
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", propertyResolver.getProperty("username"));
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", propertyResolver.getProperty("password"));
        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
        config.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean(name="mpeEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean auditEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages("com.staples.mpe.domain")
                // .packages("com.staples.mpe.domain");
                .persistenceUnit("mpe")
                . properties(additionalJpaProperties())
                .build();
    }

    Map<String,String> additionalJpaProperties(){
        Map<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        // Properties properties = new Properties();
        hm.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hm.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        hm.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return hm;
    }

    @Bean(name = "mpeTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory mpeEntityManager){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(mpeEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;

    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts("development, production");
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

AuditDatabaseConfiguration.java

```
package com.staples.em.magnus.audit.config;    
@Configuration    
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.staples.em.magnus.audit.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "auditEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "auditTransactionManager")    
@DependsOn("auditTransactionManager")    
public class AuditDatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AuditDatabaseConfiguration.class);

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment,
                "spring.datasource.secondary.");
    }

    @Bean(name = "auditDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null
                && propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName") == null) {
            log.error(
                    "Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application"
                            + "cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                    Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException(
                    "Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(propertyResolver
                .getProperty("dataSourceClassName"));
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null
                || "".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("url"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName",
                    propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName",
                    propertyResolver.getProperty("serverName"));
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("url",
                    propertyResolver.getProperty("url"));
        }
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user",
                propertyResolver.getProperty("username"));
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password",
                propertyResolver.getProperty("password"));
        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
        config.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean(name = "auditTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            EntityManagerFactory auditEntityManager) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(auditEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;

    }

    @Bean(name = "auditEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean auditEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages(PersistentAuditEvent.class).persistenceUnit("audit")
                .properties(additionalJpaProperties()).build();
    }

    Map<String, String> additionalJpaProperties() {
        Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // Properties properties = new Properties();
        hm.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hm.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        hm.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        return hm;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts("development, production");
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

below is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheConfiguration': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: mpeEntityManager,auditEntityManager
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:916) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted    

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: mpeEntityManager,auditEntityManager
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:556) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:515) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:682) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:655) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 77 common frames omitted    

ERROR | 2014-12-03 21:18:45,212 | DirectJDKLog.java | 185 | A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
```

can you please help me with this, how do i avoid this error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show more of the stack trace? Which bean is it that is failing to be wired?

Comment: sure, Thanks for looking at it. I have added the stack trace.

Comment: its failing to autowire entitymanagerfactory bean , its expecting 1 but found 2 , as I have defined 2 entitymanagerfactory beans. Thanks

Comment: I think your "cacheConfiguration" needs to specify the persistence unit name it wants to use via an annotation (`@PersistenceUnit` or `@PersistenceContext`).

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion fixed the above error,but ran in to another issue. My main application is dependent on audit module.Both main application and audit module are referring different application files. datasource properties for audit are in audit module , auditapplication.yml file, when i run the main application its not detecting the auditapplication.yml. I modified  above database configuration classes to have own propertysource, but still audit property file is not detected.can you please take a look at above modified classes with propertysource annotation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting your meaning there. Seems like a new problem, so why not accept my answer below and start a new post?

Comment: sure..i will start a new post for the property file issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your "cacheConfiguration" needs to specify the persistence unit name it wants to use via an annotation (@PersistenceUnit or @PersistenceContext)